# Adicionar valores a TextView tratamento

Tags: android

Estou criando um app de controle financeiro, é um projeto da faculdade, no local onde mostra o valor no formulário fiz uma TextView que a ser clicada abre um Dialog onde criei um teclado personalizado para colocar o valor, quando o usuário adiciona o valor e clica em ok o valor passa pra TextView exatamente como o usuário passou o valor,oq eu quero fazer é tratar esse valor, mas não conheço a forma de tratar esse valor já que sempre trabalhei com C# e comecei agora android,
ex: se o usuário adicionar um valor sem virgula quero que seja adicionado a string ,00 . se o usuário adicionar um valor ex: 15,5 quero adicionar depois do 5 + um 0.

Comment: acredito que não tenha problema o fado de ser TextView, continua sendo texto, a logica é a mesma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a classe [**DecimalFormat**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) para formatar valores numéricos, com ela você pode definir um padrão e então formatá-lo, por exemplo:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
String formatted = df.format(12345.67);

textView.setText(formatted);
```

---

Uma outra opção é utilizar a classe [**NumberFormat**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), com ela você poderá formar porcentagens, moedas, valores inteiros etc, por exemplo:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
String formatted = nf.format(12345.67);
textView.setText(formatted);
```

Comment: vou tentar aqui ver se tenho o resultado esperado

Comment: casa quando coloquei o metodo o valor que a minha TextView retornou sempre foi 123456,67, ela sempre retorta o que ta aqui: String formatted = nf.format(12345.67);

Comment: @RomãoGomes Qual deles você utilizou?

Comment: usei todos os dois, todos me retornam o valor (12345.67)